# How can I delete folders in /Library/Updates?

Tags: terminal, folders, macos

I've recently, through DiskDrill found that 18GB of my Macbook Air storage is being taken up by update folder in `/Library/Updates`. I tried to get rid of them by running various Terminal commands

```
rm -rf 001-12341

sudo rm -rf 001-12341

chflags nouchg 001-12341
sudo rm -rf 001-12341
```

Each with no sign of my files being eradicated.

I've also seen various tutorials online, which require booting into macOS recovery mode - which is something I don't want to resort to unless absolutely necessary (as it seems scary)

Is there anyway I can resolve this without a boot into recovery mode?

Cheers

Comment: Do you get any error message if you try to remove the folders? Also, can you please run `ls -aOel@ /Library/Updates` and copy/paste the result into your question?

Comment: Booting into recovery mode isn't as scary as it sounds, and it's quite well-documented.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could it be that in System Preferences > Software Update > Advanced the option "Download new updates when available" is selected and some updates are pending? In this case, I guess that unchecking that option and then installing the updates would help empty the folder. If that's not the case, another guess would be Content Caching: check if it is enabled in System Preferences > Sharing > Content Caching. In any case, I would strongly advice against deleting the contents of system folders.